# Javascript regex UK Phone - Invalid Group error

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying use the following regex within javascript in order to validate UK phone number input:

```
^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$
```

Needless to say it works in various regex testers (see: https://regex101.com/r/lJ1uS2/1) but as soon as it is plonked into some javascript and ran/instantiated it throws an invalid group error. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1sqjc0kb/

Code:

```
var reg = new RegExp("^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$","i")
```

Check console on run, and it produces:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   /^(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11))?[s-]?(?|+)44)?[s-]?(?(?:0)?[s-]?(?)?|0)(?:d{2})?[s-]?d{4}[s-]?d{4}|d{3})?[s-]?d{3}[s-]?d{3,4}|d{4})?[s-]?(?:d{5}|d{3}[s-]?d{3})|d{5})?[s-]?d{4,5}|8(?:00[s-]?11[s-]?11|45[s-]?46[s-]?4d))(?:(?:[s-]?(?:x|ext.?s?|#)d+)?)$/:
>   Invalid group

Scoured through it, can't seen anything wrong with it, no negative look behinds etc.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: It's because you're using the RegExp constructor and string literal. Either switch to a regex literal (`/<regex>/`) or double all the backslashes.

Comment: Many thanks this worked. [link] http://jsfiddle.net/1sqjc0kb/7/ <- fiddle updated to show working solution.